# Can i connect between Android and IOS By WIFI-Direct?

Tags: android, ios, wifi-direct

I Want to transfer file between Android and IOS By **WIFI-DIRECT**

Android have **WifiP2p Library**

and IOS have **MultiPear Connectivity Library**  for **WIFI-DIRECT**

BUT it is not compatible between two Libraries !!!

Each other can't found network service

**How to connect between Android and IOS to transfer file  ????**

Comment: You cannot do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `NSInputStream` & `NSOutputStream` to connect with android. It's not a simple task.

First,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSOutputStream *outputStream;
```

Then add this method,

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {

    uint portNo = 5555;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", portNo, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

You have to call this method to start the Stream.

And to send something from this stream, here is a example.

```
- (IBAction)photoClick:(id)sender {

    NSData *newData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"s.jpg"]);
    int index = 0;
    int totalLen = [newData length];
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *)[newData bytes];

    while (index < totalLen) {
        if ([outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
            NSLog(@"Sending");
            int indexLen =  (1024>(totalLen-index))?(totalLen-index):1024;

            (void)memcpy(buffer, readBytes, indexLen);

            int written = [outputStream write:buffer maxLength:indexLen];

            if (written < 0) {
                break;
            }

            index += written;

            readBytes += written;
        }
    }
}
```